# Selecting part of a field with a regex

Tags: mysql, regex, match

I've a table where a 3rd party component stores urls, i would like to get only the `id` parameter from this url.

With PHP i can do it like this:

```php
$subject = "index.php?option=com_content&catid=2&id=456&view=article"; //mysql query result
$pattern = '*[&?]id=([0-9]+)*'; //matches either ?id=456 or &id=456
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo $matches[1];//prints 456
```

The number matched would be part of a new query:

```
SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id=the_match
```

Now, i think it would be a lot faster to do it directly via mysql, something like

```
SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id = (SELECT REGEX_MATCH('*[&?]id=([0-9]+)*', '$1') FROM table2 WHERE uniquefield1 = 'fred')
```

Obviously `SELECT REGEX_MATCH('*[&?]id=([0-9]+)*', '$1') FROM table2 WHERE uniquefield1 = 'fred')` is completely invented, just to say that i want to select the first group matched from regex and use it to make the `WHERE` clause work.

Is it possible to do something like this with MySQL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**This answer is obsolete. MySql has better regex support.**

No, sad to say MySQL doesn't have a way to apply a regex to a column's contents in a SELECT clause, only a WHERE clause.

But you can use ordinary (non-regex) string manipulation functions to do this. If the column containing your ampersand-separated parameter string is named `url`, you can get the id number with this fine string expression, which finds your id number.

```
  CAST(RIGHT(url, LENGTH(url) - 3 - LOCATE('&id=', url)) AS SIGNED INTEGER)
```

So, if you want a list of `id` values from the `url` columns of `table1`, you could use this `SELECT` query.

```
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(url, LENGTH(url) - 3 - 
                       LOCATE('&id=', url)) AS SIGNED INTEGER) AS id
  FROM table1
 WHERE url REGEXP '&id=[0-9]+'
```

As you can see this uses the regexp search function to locate the appropriate rows.

There is nothing fast about this. Regexp matching can't exploit a MySQL index.  If you have the choice of loading your table with the id column pre-extracted you'll be much better off searching when your table gets big.

Comment: Well, that can be useful too, can you post an example of using regexes in a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: My column is named `origurl`, so i tried this `SELECT CAST(RIGHT(origurl, LENGTH(origurl) - 3 - LOCATE('&id=', origurl)) AS INTEGER) AS id FROM j_sefurls WHERE origurl REGEXP '&id=[0-9]+'`, it says _#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS id FROM j_sefurls WHERE origurl REGEXP '&id=[0-9]+' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1_

Comment: It's hard for me to debug your SQL, but when I cut and paste this exact statement into my test system (MySQL 5.5) it worked fine.

Comment: Aha, different syntax in my version of MySQL. Try `SIGNED INTEGER` instead of `INTEGER` in the `CAST`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7738f/13/0

Comment: That's ugly as hell. But I agree it does the job. In my case I even don't need the regex anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Is possible to use this package: [mysql-udf-regexp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp)

The functions implemented by this package are:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(text, pattern [, mode])
REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, pattern [,position [,occurence [,mode]]])
REGEXP_INSTR?(text, pattern [,position [,occurence [,return_end [,mode]]]])
REGEXP_REPLACE?(text, pattern, replace [,position [,occurence [,return_end [,mode]]])
```

Very similar to the Oracle SQL functions.

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't do it as I'm on a shared webserver and I cannot install php or mysql plugins. Good to know it exists though.