# Extract Numbers from a string in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to either remove all characters from a string, or extract the numbers and store the numbers in a temporary table.

Here is what I have so far:

```
drop table if exists T_Stores;
create temporary table T_Stores(
    store varchar(50)
);


insert into T_Stores
select p.pev_nms from bsgtran.pev p where p.pev_nms regexp '(new|relo|under).*store'
;
```

It currently saves the value from `p.pev_nms` into the `store` column. Which looks MANY different ways `New Store 00001` or `New Store 00001 CA` or `New Store 00001 1st St., New York, NY` and many other different combinations. How can I extract the 5 digit characters from the string?

Comment: mysql regexes are for matching only. there's no capturing or replacement or extracting. you'll have to use standard string operations to pull things out.

Comment: This might lend itself better to a script.

Comment: I think I got what I want, by doing a join onto my stores table like this: `left join bsg.stores s on (
    p.pev_nms like concat('%', s.st_nbr, '%')
    or p.pev_notes like concat('%', s.st_nbr, '%')
)`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392197/selecting-part-of-a-field-with-a-regex